# Short story same as the "Lucy" movie

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, lucy

I am trying to remember the name and the author of a short story that seems to have a similar plot to the Besson's movie "Lucy".

I read that stories more than 30 years ago: A scientist made an evolution experiment on a man and a woman. The man de-evolves to a beast and the woman evolves to have God-like power, having to fight against people trying to control her.

I remember having read classic "pulps" authors at that time.

---

I have browsed lot of novella descriptions. There is one that seems to match, "Research Alpha" - Van Vogt (1965).  It features an "evolution serum" and "big IQ levels". Unfortunately, I don't have the book at hand. If someone would check it that would be great.

---

This list has been submitted by Deepak

- *Flowers for Algernon* by Daniel Keyes
- *The Dark Fields* by Alan Glynn
- *Understand* by Ted Chiang.

Comment: Are you saying it's got the same plot (e.g. that one is based on the other) or just that it employs similar tropes (e.g. http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/DevolutionDevice)

Comment: @Richard The movie remembered that story, I'm just trying to remember the title. Similarity is :  "some science gave power to the woman, the woman has growing power, others are trying to stop her".

Comment: Do you remember his or her name, what powers she gained, why they wanted to fight her, did you used to subscribe to any magazines/where did you read it?

Comment: There's another one that I thought was more similar to Lucy, that does not match your description.  It already has a story-id question somewhere on here, though

Comment: @Richard I think I have found, sorry for the misdirection, that's not a "pulp".

Comment: It seems that Van Vogt stitched together 3 of his older stories into the book *Supermind*, the last of which was "Research Alpha"--the description of the last story in *Supermind* at http://brianbookreviews.blogspot.com/2011/10/supermind-by-ae-van-vogt.html does sound just like the story you remembered, start with the paragraph "In the third segment, which bears upon the previous two not at all..." Not sure if the story was altered to fit it together with the other two, but it seems "Research Alpha" is available as a standalone story in the book *More Than Superhuman*.

Comment: BTW, since you found it yourself, you might as well post it as the answer yourself...

Comment: @Hypnosifl  I didn't remember she was going to mate anyone. Perhaps the "More than Superhuman" version is different in that regard. Note that "More than Superhuman" looks familiar to me I think read it translated.

Comment: Apart from the one you were thinking of, there are many excellent "enhanced cognition" stories out there. *Flowers for Algernon* (by Daniel Keyes) is a staple. Then of course, there's *The Dark Fields* (by Alan Glynn) which was the basis for the popular movie  (and screenplay) *Limitless*. Finally, and this is the one that I think is closest to *Lucy* - check out the novella *Understand* by Ted Chiang. Unfortunately, it's no longer freely available online, but I found it awesome. This work actually explores the "superhuman" transformational aspect of extreme enhancement just like Lucy does.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You've pinpointed the correct story in the comments, so if you want to add your own answer I'll delete this. For now I'll answer in case anyone wants more information.

The story is called "Research Alpha" and was cowritten by Van Vogt and James H. Schmitz. It appeared in the anthology *More than Superhuman*, and also also appeared as a subplot in the novel *Supermind*. Van Vogt had a tendency to bolt together his short stories to make novels - not always with happy results.

Spoilers follow:

The underlying idea is that the Great Galactics have injected some of their own genes into the races they encounter, but during human evolution these genes have become unevenly distributed. The scientist Dr Gloge is working on a project called Point Omega Stimulation which aims to enhance human evolution. Gloge secretly injects two people, Barbara Ellington and Vincent Strather with the Omega serum. Barbara possesses an unusually favourable package of Great Galactic genes and the serum enhances these so she basically turns into a Great Galactic. In Vincent the serum enhances other genes and he becomes a goblin like figure - it's implied but not stated explicitly that he's become mentally subnormal.

In *Supermind* it's made clear that this is a deliberate manipulation by the Great Galactic William Leigh. He had detected the favourable genes in Barbara and wanted her to attain her full potential so he can have her as a companion. Vincent was included in the experiment to demonstrate to mankind that the process would mostly fail so it shouldn't be used routinely. As far as I recall this aspect of the plot is absent from the original short story.

Vincent recovers, so it's a happy ending :-)

Comment: I'm glad you answered, writing in English causes me some troubles.

Comment: @user14111 Thanks. Somehow I have managed to spend the last fifty years believing Van Vogt was the sole author.

Answer (score 0):

The short story "Understand" that's in the book "Stories of Your Life and Others" by Ted Chiang follows a very similar premise.
A man in a coma is injected with an experimental drug called Hormone K which regenerates neurons and allows the subject to develop hyper intelligence which they can use to even influence other people's biological processes

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Is there another character who, injected with the same drug, devolves?  That seems to be an important part of the question.